# Real projective space homeomorphic to sphere

Tags: general-topology

Consider the unit sphere $S^n$ with the equivalence relation that identifies antipodal points of $S^n$. Show that the quotient space $S^n/\sim$ is homeomorphic to the projective space $\mathbb{RP}^n$.

I know that $\mathbb{RP}^n=\overline{B^n}/\sim$, so if I can define a homeomorphism from $\overline{B^n}$ to $S^n$, I think that should be sufficient. My thought was to define a function on the ball so that every point on a line that goes through the origin is mapped to the outermost point, a point on the sphere. But I don't know how to write this explicitly. I have seen questions like this stated, with the explanation I came up with given, but there is no explicit definition of the homeomorphism.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Thanks, but the answer there does not give an explicit definition of the homeomorphism.

Comment: There is no homeomorphism from $\overline{B^n}$ to $\Bbb S^n$ (their $n$th homotopy groups differ). On the other hand there *is* a map $\overline{B^n} \to \Bbb S^n$ whose composition $\overline{B^n} \to \Bbb S^n \to \Bbb S^n / \sim$ descends to a homeomorphism $\Bbb R \Bbb P^n \stackrel{\cong}{\to} \Bbb S^n / \sim$---this is the construction given in the answer Moishe Cohen linked.